# mhchem: hpstatement is not working

Tags: mhchem

What am I doing wrong? I tried to do hazard statements and precautionary statements in my document, but the `\hpstatement{}` command is not working, as described in the `mhchem` manual.

My MWE (or not working):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{hpstatement}
\usepackage{rsphrase}


\begin{document}

The statement \hpnumber{H200}\\
is ‘\hpstatement{H200}’

\end{document}
```

This prints only:

[image: The printout]

And errors:

```
Package hpstatement Error: You have to specify an H or P statement number

(hpstatement)                when you use \hpnumber for the first time
(hpstatement)                (e.g. \hpnumber{H200}).

See the hpstatement package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 The statement \hpnumber{H200}
                                  \\
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

```
Package hpstatement Error: H or P statement "H200"

(hpstatement)                is not defined.

See the hpstatement package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 is ‘\hpstatement{H200}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers and statements only work if an explicit language is specified with `babel`. This can be considered a bug (which can be resolved by setting English as the default language for `hpstatement`). Supported languages are English, French, German.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{hpstatement}
\usepackage{rsphrase}

\begin{document}

The statement \hpnumber{H200}\\
is ‘\hpstatement{H200}’

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! :) This solves the problem.

Comment: The most-recent version of hpstatement fixed this shortcoming. Babel is not needed any more.